# Find multiple updated column in trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I need to identify multiple column updates in a table and store them in a Audit table.
Here is Audit Schema:

```
 auditid   auditTimestamps updateFieldName  oldFieldValue  newFieldValue
```

We have another table employee with schema:

```
  EmpID  EmpName  Age  Address1  Phone
```

I wrote update trigger on employee schema, when record gets updated , trigger was fired and on trigger i check which field value was updated and maintain this info on audit table schema.

```
 For checking field for update , i have used below code sample:

    BEGIN 
           if update(empName)
           begin 
              set @updatedcolumnname='empName';
              set @newvendorname=(SELECT empNameFROM inserted);
              set @oldvendorname=(SELECT empNameFROM deleted);
              //Here insert logic that insert above find values into audit table.
            end

              // Same check for all remaining fields( Age,Address1,Phone) 
   END
```

But it's seem to be not work for me. it's insert all column that are update and not updated into audit table.

Please suggest how to could implement above functionally.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) command instead of insert command in your trigger. Also you can calculate your changed column by following query:

```
SELECT 'empName' AS FieldName, d.empName AS OldValue, i.empName AS NewValue
FROM Inserted i
INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.EmpID = i.EmpID  
WHERE i.EmpName<>d.ImpName

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Age', d.Age, i.Age
FROM Inserted i
INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.EmpID = i.EmpID
WHERE i.Age<>d.Age

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Address1', d.Address1, i.Address1
FROM Inserted i
INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.EmpID = i.EmpID
WHERE i.Address1<>d.Address1

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Phone', d.Phone, i.Phone
FROM Inserted i
INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.EmpID = i.EmpID
WHERE i.Phone<>d.Phone
```

So Your Query :

```
MERGE AuditTable AS Destination
USING (
        SELECT 'empName' AS FieldName, d.empName AS OldValue, i.empName AS NewValue
        FROM Inserted i
        INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.EmpID = i.EmpID
        WHERE i.EmpName<>d.ImpName

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 'Age', d.Age, i.Age
        FROM Inserted i
        INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.EmpID = i.EmpID
        WHERE i.Age<>d.Age

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 'Address1', d.Address1, i.Address1
        FROM Inserted i
        INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.EmpID = i.EmpID
        WHERE i.Address1<>d.Address1

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 'Phone', d.Phone, i.Phone
        FROM Inserted i
        INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.EmpID = i.EmpID
        WHERE i.Phone<>d.Phone

    ) AS SOURCE ON SOURCE.FieldName = Destination.UpdateFieldName 
                AND SOURCE.OldValue = Destination.OldFieldValue
                AND SOURCE.NewValue = Destinatino.NewFieldValue
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET OldFieldValue  = OldValue,
                                NewFieldValue = NewValue
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (UpdateFieldName, OldFieldValue, NewFieldValue) 
                        VALUES(FieldName, OldValue,NewValue)
```

Comment: sql server displaying "Invalid column name 'Id'." for d.Id = i.Id.pls suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: Nowhere in his answer did he use the string "d.id" or any field named just "id". He did reference an "empID" which is what you stated was the key of the employee table.